# How to load data into snowflake table from json.gz file

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to insert records from my json.gz file into snowflake table.
I created this steps:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT test_gz TYPE = JSON

                     
create stage my_test_stage

  storage_integration = MY_S3

  url = 's3://mybucket/'

  file_format = test_gz;

 



  copy into test_table

  from @my_test_stage
```

I have an error: JSON file can produce one and only one column of type variant or object or array.
I also tried to change file format to gzip but it's not working.

Comment: I believe the error is quite explanatory - does your target table have only one column of type variant and its still failing?

Comment: @Pankaj my table has two columns name varchar(50) and email varchar(50). My json.gz looks like this: {"name":"John", "email":"xxx"}.

Comment: You need to create a table to first hold raw data from json (table with only one column type variant) and then you can copy from that to main table. Or, Try this copy into test_table(col_name_1, col_name_2) from (select $1:name,$1:email from @stage_name)

Comment: @Pankaj I had to use copy into test_table(name,email) from (select split($:name,'.'),split ($1: email,'.') from @my_test_stage);

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to add
`CREATE FILE FORMAT test_gz TYPE = JSON COMPRESSION=GZIP` instead of just `TYPE = JSON`

Make sure your dest table looking like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test_table (JSON_DATA VARIANT)
```

Either way you can execute this all at once:

```
copy into test_table
from 's3://mybucket/'
storage_integration = MY_S3
file_format = (type = json COMPRESSION=GZIP)
```